# Jenkins Parameterized Build Page Cannot be Displayed

Tags: jenkins

We have a basic install of Jenkins.  When I create a parameterized build and then try the "Build Now" option all I get is a page can not be displayed.  This is all done with using the Jenkins GUI and nothing special.  If I create another job and call the parameterized job with the parameter it works fine.

Any recomonendations?

Jenkins Ver 1.496 running on WAS 8.5 server

[image: PARAMETERIZED BUILD SCREEN SHOT]

**Edit 01/05/2013**

Thinking this could be possibly an issue between IE and other browsers I tried in Google Chrome today and at least I got some more information to show.

[image: CHROME ERROR]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your job configuration?

Comment: Added screen shot of setting build is parameterized.